# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'double' , flutter error while using twitter api

Tags: flutter, api, twitter

Error appeared in my terminal

[image]

Here I used two dart packages, which one is to call api and get JSON file,I printed in terminal and it works fine
[image]

But While I am using the twitter_ui package , It returns me an error message as shown above. Packages link are
https://pub.dev/packages/tweet_ui

Tweet.fromJson requires a JSON to pass as an argument , I passed the first element of the List I created when I using API package.

This is my code

```
import 'package:dart_twitter_api/twitter_api.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:tweet_ui/embedded_tweet_view.dart';
import 'package:tweet_ui/models/api/tweet.dart' as ui;

final twitterApi = TwitterApi(
  client: TwitterClient(
    consumerKey: '',
    consumerSecret: '',
    token: '',
    secret: '',
  ),
);

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Map<String,dynamic>>? homeTile;
  Future<void> getTwitter() async {
    final homeTimeline = await twitterApi.timelineService.userTimeline(
      userId: "41786801",

      count: 200,
    );

    // Print the text of each Tweet

    homeTile = homeTimeline.map((tweet) {
      return tweet.toJson();
    }).toList();
    print("Vilakshan");

    print(homeTile![0]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    (() async {
      await getTwitter();
      setState(() {

      });
    })();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child:(homeTile!=null) ? buildEmbeddedTweetView(
              homeTile![0], true):CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),);
  }
}

Widget buildEmbeddedTweetView(Map<String,dynamic> jsonFile, bool darkMode) {
  return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 20),
          child: EmbeddedTweetView.fromTweet(
            ui.Tweet.fromJson(
              jsonFile,
            ),
            backgroundColor: (darkMode) ? Colors.grey[800]! : Colors.white,
            darkMode: darkMode,
            createdDateDisplayFormat: DateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy"),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: I think you are getting something double value instead null. Try to change or modify the list.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am trying the tweet_ui too, but I do not know how to generate the json file such as tweet_1_photos.json in the example.

Comment: twitter api dart has some errors. Find out that errors and change it in package. Twitter UI is correct